# Azure media player multiple instances volume issue

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I am using multiple instances of azure media player. The problem is that I have multiple instances, the player's volume control stops working. Is there any workaround for this? I am using vuejs. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

anyone who looks for a solution for the volume (mute and unmute too) issues. The only workaround i found to fix the issues is to use a iframe for the player. Basically i created a html file with the player and loading it via iframe.

For example my videoplayer.html (HTML) looks like this:
https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/samples/dynamic_setsource.html

And my iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe src="/bla/bla/videoplayer.html?video=https://thevideourl.manifest&otherparam=xx&andsomethingelse="yyy"></iframe>
```

Im also passing the some params via get parameter to the iframe. So i can use the params inside the iframe to make it more dynamic.

This way you can embed multiple player on the same page and the player works like excepted. Currently its not possible to use the Azure Media Player on the same page multiple times without control issues.